# Populating JSON result to GridView using onTextChanged

Tags: android, json, gridview

Hi i am having a bit of problem on how to populate JSON result using onTextChange.

What i am trying to do is to update the content of my GridView whenever the text on a specific EditText is changed.

The following is what i have done so far:

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_people);

    /* INITIALIZES GRID ITEMS */
    gridView.setAdapter(new SearchGridAdapter(this));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub;
        }
    });

    TextWatcher fieldValidator = new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(longEnough()){
                doSearch(txtSearchPpl.getText().toString().trim());
            }
        }

        private boolean longEnough() {
            return txtSearchPpl.getText().toString().trim().length() > 3;
        }
    };

    txtSearchPpl.addTextChangedListener(fieldValidator);

private void doSearch(String keywords){
    SearchPerson task = new SearchPerson();
    task.execute(keywords);
}
```

**While my Adapter looks like this**:

```
public class SearchGridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

public SearchGridAdapter(Context context){
    super(context, R.layout.grid_item_text);
    mContext = context;
    mPeople = null;
}

public SearchGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Person> people){
    super(context, R.layout.grid_item_text);
    mContext = context;
    mPeople = people;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mPeople == null){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return mPeople.size();
    }

}

@Override
public Person getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mPeople.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_text,
            parent, false);

    TextView personName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textItem);
    ImageView personThumb = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iconItem);

    personName.setText(mPeople.get(position).fullName);
    personThumb.setImageResource(mThumbs);
    return view;
}
```

}

**And onPostExecute i did this:**

```
*** REST OF CODE OMITTED ***
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<Person> result) {         
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if(result != null){
                    gridView.setAdapter(new SearchGridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), result));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The code above works, but it throws some unintentional behaviour. If i type "Ruby" the first time it displays the result correctly, however when i continue typing "Ruby Palmer" the activity crashed (the app is still running).

Can anyone point me to the right direction here? Thx.

EDIT #1:

I removed the onUiThread and it gives me the following error:

FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
at x.x.x.SearchPeopleActivity$SearchPerson.doInBackground(SearchPeopleActivity.java:231)

EDIT #2:

I figured out the error on EDIT #1, now i implement a simple if checks on doInBackground()

```
@Override
protected ArrayList<Person> doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String keyword = params[0];
    String resultData = ((new HttpRetriever())).searchPerson(myAccount.email, myAccount.passwd, keyword);
    Log.i("THUMBQOO", resultData);
    try {
        if(resultData != null){
            mSearchResult = (new ContactHandlers()).personResult(resultData);
        }else{
            mSearchResult = null;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("THUMBQOO - REG PHONE", "JSON Exception");
    }
    return mSearchResult;
}
```

However, the original problem persists. When i type "Ruby" the grid displays all name contains Ruby. However, if i continue typing Ruby Pal the activity crashed (the app is still running). And reset the GridView with no items.

Comment: get rid of runOnUiThread in onPostExecute, it is already called on the UI thread, and it causes it to immediately be run on the UI thread instead of put in queue, which could be causing your problem.

Comment: and what does LogCat say when it crashes, post it.

Comment: Hi i did remove the runOnUiThread, now the app is crashing. See edit #1 for Log Cat Error.

Answer (score 0):

@svenoaks Thanks for the suggestion. It works as i want it to be. The later problem is due to improper URI builder.

So basically this is what i did (removing the onUiThread)

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<Person> result) {  
        if(result != null){
            gridView.setAdapter(new SearchGridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), result));
        }
    }
```